# Turn an output stream for a program into array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an output stream for a program which contains list of available printers and I want to turn it into array.

This is my stdout:

```sh
OneNote                        

Microsoft XPS Document Writer  

Microsoft Print to PDF         

Fax
```

And I am seeking for a solution that will give me:

```
['OneNote', 'Microsoft XPS Document Writer', 'Microsoft Print to PDF', 'Fax']
```

I tried `stdout.split('\n')`, but it became

```
[
 'OneNote                        \r\r', 
 'Microsoft XPS Document Writer  \r\r', 
 'Microsoft Print to PDF         \r\r', 
 'Fax                            \r\r',
 '\r\r',
 ''
]
```

Then I tried `stdout.split('\r\r\n')` and it turns into

```
[
 'OneNote                        ', 
 'Microsoft XPS Document Writer  ', 
 'Microsoft Print to PDF         ', 
 'Fax                            ',
 '',
 ''
]
```

Now I can removes whitespace from ends of the strings `stdout.split('\r\r\n').map(printer => printer.trim())` but I still need to filter out last two empty strings, so I was wondering is there any better/elegant way to solve the problem?

```
stdout.split('\r\r\n')
  .map(printer => printer.trim())
  .filter(printer => Boolean(printer.length))
```

Comment: `trim()` the string before splitting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression -

```
input.trim().split(/\s*[\r\n]+\s*/)
```

See it working in this complete program below -

```js
const input = 
`
OneNote                        

Microsoft XPS Document Writer  

Microsoft Print to PDF         

Fax                            
`

const output =
  input.trim().split(/\s*[\r\n]+\s*/)
  
console.log(output)
// [
//   "OneNote",
//   "Microsoft XPS Document Writer",
//   "Microsoft Print to PDF",
//   "Fax"
// ]
```

The regular expression targets any carriage returns `\r` and/or line feeds `\n` surrounded by optional whitespace. It can be understood as -

- `\s*` - zero-or-more whitespace, followed by
- `[\r\n]+` - one-or-more `\r` or `\n`, followed by
- `\s*` - zero-or-more whitespace